# Sending data via a queue in FreeRTOS

Tags: c, freertos

I have got two files with code.

1. Ethernet
2. CAN

And between this files I would like sending data. 
So, in the **CAN file** I created structure:

```
struct screenData {
        uint16_t gyroskop_x;
        uint16_t gyroskop_y;
        uint16_t gyroskop_z;
        uint16_t euler_x;
        uint16_t euler_y;
        uint16_t euler_z;
    } data;
```

And I tried initialise of this structure with my test values.

```
struct screenData * toSend;
    data.gyroskop_x = 1;
    data.gyroskop_y = 2;
    data.gyroskop_z = 3;
    data.euler_x = 4;
    data.euler_y = 5;
    data.euler_z = 6;
    toSend = &data;
```

And I created new task, whrere I sending data every 1s.

```
xQueueSend ( fronta_gyroskop, ( void * ) &toSend , 10 );
```

In **ethernet file** I initialise queue.
In ethernet file:

1. initialise queue
2. Created receive structure for data
3. Receive data from queue

Code

```
xQueueHandle fronta_gyroskop = 0;

extern void init_queue(void)
 {
   fronta_gyroskop = xQueueCreate(6, sizeof(struct ethernetData *));
 }

struct ethernetData {
        uint16_t gyroskop_x;
        uint16_t gyroskop_y;
        uint16_t gyroskop_z;
        uint16_t euler_x;
        uint16_t euler_y;
        uint16_t euler_z;
    } gyro;
```

And in task I receive data every 1second.

```
if (xQueueReceive(fronta_gyroskop, &gyro, 20)){ 
}
```

But the values in gyro aren't my values (1,2,3,4,5,6), but the values are random 32bit values. Any idea, what I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

CAN side code

```
#include "Tasky/Ethernet.h"
void *fronta_gyroskop;

can_mb_conf_t tx_mailbox;
can_mb_conf_t rx_mailbox;
/** Receive status */
volatile uint32_t g_ul_recv_status = 0;

void CAN0_Handler(void)
{
    uint32_t ul_status;

    ul_status = can_mailbox_get_status(CAN0, 0);
    if (ul_status & CAN_MSR_MRDY) {
        rx_mailbox.ul_status = ul_status;
        can_mailbox_read(CAN0, &rx_mailbox);
        g_ul_recv_status = 1;
    }
}

struct screenData {
        uint16_t gyroskop_x;
        uint16_t gyroskop_y;
        uint16_t gyroskop_z;
        uint16_t euler_x;
        uint16_t euler_y;
        uint16_t euler_z;
    } data;

extern void task_can_read(void *pvParameters)
{
    UNUSED(pvParameters);
    const portTickType xDelayTime = 10;
    uint8_t nacti = 1;

    /* init test value to sending */
    struct screenData * toSend;
    data.gyroskop_x = 1;
    data.gyroskop_y = 2;
    data.gyroskop_z = 3;
    data.euler_x = 4;
    data.euler_y = 5;
    data.euler_z = 6;
    toSend = &data;

    for (;;){
        if (!g_ul_recv_status) {
            //puts("zadna zprava na CAN sbernici\r");
        } else {
            if ((rx_mailbox.ul_id >> 18) == FIRST_GYRO_ID) //rotation to 11bit number
            {
                //calculate
                nacti = 1;
            }

            if ((rx_mailbox.ul_id >> 18) == SECOND_GYRO_ID)
            {
                //calculate
                xQueueSend ( fronta_gyroskop, ( void * ) &data , 10 );  //send data over queue
                nacti = 0;
            }

            if (nacti == 1)
            {
                rx_mailbox.ul_id = CAN_MID_MIDvA(SECOND_GYRO_ID);
                can_mailbox_init(CAN0, &rx_mailbox);
            }
            if (nacti == 0)
            {
                rx_mailbox.ul_id = CAN_MID_MIDvA(FIRST_GYRO_ID);
                can_mailbox_init(CAN0, &rx_mailbox);
            }

            g_ul_recv_status = 0;   //clear flag
        }

        vTaskDelay(xDelayTime);
    }
}
```

ETH code

```
#include "Tasky/CAN_TASKs.h"

struct tcp_pcb *output = NULL;
void *dataeth;

struct netif gs_net_if;
uint32_t g_ip_mode;
int8_t g_c_ipconfig[];

struct ethernetData {
        uint16_t gyroskop_x;
        uint16_t gyroskop_y;
        uint16_t gyroskop_z;
        uint16_t euler_x;
        uint16_t euler_y;
        uint16_t euler_z;
    } gyro;


/************************************************************************/
/*                  INIT QUEU to analyze data from TCPIP                */
/************************************************************************/
xQueueHandle fronta_gyroskop = 0;

extern void init_fronta_ethernet(void)
{
    fronta_gyroskop = xQueueCreate(6, sizeof(struct ethernetData *));
}

/************************************************************************/
/*                  TASK of FREERTOS to TCPIP                           */
/************************************************************************/
extern void TCP_connection(void *pvParameters)
{
    UNUSED(pvParameters);

    const portTickType xDelayTime = 1000 / portTICK_RATE_MS;

    uint16_t trest[6];

    while (1){  

        if (xQueueReceive(fronta_gyroskop, &gyro, 10)){ //receive data over queue
            tcp_write(output, (void *)&gyro, sizeof(gyro), TCP_WRITE_FLAG_COPY);    //Write data for sending (but does not send it immediately)
            tcp_sent(output, NULL); //Used to specify the function that should be called when TCP data has been successfully delivered to the remote host
            tcp_output(output); //Find out what we can send and send it.
        }
        vTaskDelay(xDelayTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you checking values inside `if (xQueueReceive(fronta_gyroskop, &gyro, 20))` ? Are you sure `fronta_gyroskop != NULL`?

Comment: Yes. I check velues inside (gyro).
[link](http://s23.postimg.org/afygiemxn/check.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Problem was solved.

Wrong initialization of queue.

```
fronta_gyroskop = xQueueCreate(6, sizeof(struct ethernetData *));
```

Here is good init.

```
fronta_gyroskop = xQueueCreate(6, sizeof(struct ethernetData));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
xQueueSend ( fronta_gyroskop, ( void * ) &toSend , 10 );
```

You are sending address of pointer to data.

To send data you must send address of data directly:

```
xQueueSend ( fronta_gyroskop, ( void * ) &data , 10 );
```

Comment: Ouu. So I corrected xQueueSend to this:
xQueueSend ( fronta_gyroskop, ( void * ) &data , 10 );

Now are first and second values is true, but other values is wrong. 
Here is screenshot of values. [link](http://s15.postimg.org/q3l72tugb/values.jpg)

Comment: @Jirka What is `data` scope? Is it local (stack allocated) into a function or global?

Comment: `data` is global 
Here is my CAN file:[CAN FILE](http://paste.ofcode.org/79BfWQ8sXqbfZ5UPiMLjgB)
And here is my ETH file: [ETH FILE](http://paste.ofcode.org/tMJNjCZgpnxcauhUw6Xps2)